# StoreKit crash only ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I got this crash from crashlytics. Do you know what is that mean? The crashlytics says; 100% crash from ios 10. I searched this bug, but I couldn't anything about it.

**Edit:** **Crash Title**

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000**

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x186af6f30 objc_msgSend + 16
1  StoreKit                       0x194ad1d0c <redacted> + 52
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x186f35200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x186f351c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x186f39d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
5  CoreFoundation                 0x188059f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6  CoreFoundation                 0x188057b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
7  CoreFoundation                 0x187f86048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
8  GraphicsServices               0x189a09198 GSEventRunModal + 180
9  UIKit                          0x18df60628 <redacted> + 684
10 UIKit                          0x18df5b360 UIApplicationMain + 208
11 AppName                       0x100126770 main (main.m:15)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x186f685b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: You are more likely to receive a satisfactory answer if you include more information and more details from the crash log and perhaps affected methods.

Comment: @breakingobstacles yeah i know, but i only have this information from crashlytics. I can add crash title.

Comment: Actually, that additional bit of info is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors often occur when trying to send a message to an object that has been deallocated, or to nil.

In this case, the associated address `0x0000000000000000` and the top item `objc_msgSend` makes it pretty clear: a message was sent to a nil/null object.

If your code works on previous version of iOS, it may be because the object isn't being released at the same time, or because there is some new behavior of the APIs you are using that you aren't handling (for example: maybe an earlier function/API call now returns nil in iOS 10, but you just pass that through to somewhere else without checking it).